# How can I make a recursive CTE query in an ActiveRecord scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have a simple table to represent a hierarchy of organizations:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.organizations (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_id integer,
    deleted_at timestamp without time zone
)
```

The objective is, given some query for some organizations, to expand those results to include all the descendendants. In Postgres, this can be done with a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), like this:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE "all_orgs" AS (
  SELECT "organizations".*
  FROM "organizations"
  /* some filter, maybe some joins here */

  UNION

  SELECT "organizations".*
  FROM "organizations"
  INNER JOIN "all_orgs" ON "all_orgs"."id" = "organizations"."parent_id"
)
SELECT "all_orgs".* FROM "all_orgs"
```

I would like to program a reusable way to include all the descendents for any arbitrary initial set of organizations. So naturally, I attempted to implement a scope:

```
class Organization << ApplicationRecord
  scope :recursive_child_orgs, ->(root_orgs) do
    all_orgs = Arel::Table.new(:all_orgs)

    join_constraint = Arel::Nodes::On.new(all_orgs[:id].eq(arel_table[:parent_id]))
    join_node = Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(all_orgs, join_constraint)
    child_orgs = joins(join_node)
    
    union = root_orgs.arel.union(child_orgs.arel)
    
    recursive_cte = Arel::SelectManager.new(all_orgs).tap do |sm|
      sm.with(:recursive, Arel::Nodes::As.new(all_orgs, union))
      sm.project(all_orgs[Arel::star])
    end
    
    from(recursive_cte.as(table_name))
  end
end
```

It would be used something like `Organization.recursive_child_orgs(Organization.where(id: 3))` (In practice the inner part of that expression would be something less trivial.)

This is tantalizingly close, generating the query:

```
SELECT "organizations".* FROM (
    WITH RECURSIVE "all_orgs" AS ( 
      SELECT "organizations".* 
      FROM "organizations"
      WHERE "organizations"."deleted_at" IS NULL
      AND "organizations"."id" = /* note: missing value! */
    
      UNION
    
      SELECT "organizations".* 
      FROM "organizations" 
      INNER JOIN "all_orgs" ON "all_orgs"."id" = "organizations"."parent_id"
      WHERE "organizations"."deleted_at" IS NULL
    )
    SELECT "all_orgs".* FROM "all_orgs"
) organizations
WHERE "organizations"."deleted_at" IS NULL;
```

The default scope for `Organization` was included, nice! And the whole CTE mess is bundled up as a thing named `organizations`, which means it looks to ActiveRecord to be the organizations table, so adding sorting and whatnot after the recursive bit should work.

But unfortunately, the bound parameter that was introduced with `Organization.where(id: 3)` does not survive the translation, and a syntactically invalid statement is generated as a result. How might this be fixed?